# How to get reference of MAIN controller in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs, controller

How to get reference of controller in EXTJS?

Sencha template generates main view for modern application as:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    xtype: 'main',
    id: 'main',

    controller: 'main',

    platformConfig: {
        phone: {
            controller: 'phone-main'
        }
    },
    
...
```

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',
```

The first thing that I do not understand is that there are two controllers (`main` and `phone-main`). I suppose that `phone-main` is for as its name suggests phone. But isn't modern toolkit for phones?  And in which of those two containers to put user defined functions?

Anyway, I have some functions in `main` controller and I would like to get reference of that controller, because I would like to call that functions from another controller. And I tried to get reference of the main controller like:

```
aa = Ext.getCmp('main');
ref = aa.getController();
```

but that gives me reference to `phone-main` and not to `main` controller.

I also tried:

```
ref = MyApp.app.getController('main');
```

but, that doesn't work at all. The same is for:

```
ref = MyApp.app.getController('MyApp.view.main.MainController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample depends on device (phone or desktop) appropriate ViewController will be attached:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',
    fooProperty: 'fooMainValue'

});
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.PhoneMainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.phone-main',
    fooProperty: 'fooPhoneValue'

});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    xtype: 'main',
    id: 'main',
    controller: 'main',
    platformConfig: {
        phone: {
            controller: 'phone-main'
        }
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'First',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Click me',
            handler: function () {
                console.log(this.up('main').getController().fooProperty);
            }
        }]
    }]
});

Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    height: 200
});
```

Just click in chrome developer tools on "toggle device toolbar", depends on device will be printed 'fooMainValue' or 'fooPhoneValue' property. More read [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.ClassManager.html#cfg-platformConfig).
"And in which of those two containers to put user defined functions?" => It means you can have two different controllers for phone and desktop devices or you can create one base class ViewController and extend desktop and phone controller with custom logic for different devices. General methods/properties will be placed in parent(base) controller, custom in child controller classes.

"But isn't modern toolkit for phones?" => Hm.. AFAIK they tried to develop something new.. read [this](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?470804-Make-Official-comment-on-Classic-vs-Modern&p=1321333&viewfull=1#post1321333) from ex-insider.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I have tried to call that from different places. What exactly does 'this' refer to?

Comment: I have updated the answer with fiddle sample.

Comment: Arthur, it seems you  didn't understand the core of my question. I asked about specific case created from admin-dashboard template, where there is another controller phone- main. Your code works well, but this is trivial case. The problem with platformConfig is that I always get the reference of that controller phone-main.

Comment: Ok, may you provide some fiddle sample?

Comment: Sorry, I cant. I tried, but I don't know how to make fiddle of that.